# get half of all repeating elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

My goal is to create a list with half of the individual items repeating. In the list below I have given an example. In this list, except for the first element, each marked element is repeated 2n times, therefore all elements are even and divisible by 2. I can't create a list comprehension that divides by 2 the number of times each element is repeated. For example the element: `[0, 255, 0]` is repeated 6 times in the list; I expect in my new list to be repeated only 3 times.

Input list:

```py
[[255, 255, 255], [255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0],
 [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0]]
```

Expected output list:

```py
[[255, 255, 255], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0]]
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "repeating".  It would be useful if you provided what you have tried, and this might give a sense of what you are trying to do.

Comment: What if a value appears an odd number of times, like seven times? And do you mean consecutive repetitions or can they be interrupted by other values and are still regarded as repeated?

Comment: Do you mean that if you find repeated items, you want number of them is divided by two, but if it occurs only once let it be?

Comment: Are you saying your list is *always* a single element followed by even-length streaks?

Comment: No, I'll give you an example. The element: [0, 255, 0] is repeated 6 times in the list; I expect in my new list to be repeated only 3 times.

Comment: What are you responding to? Doesn't fit any of our comments.

Comment: What's a "marked" element?

Comment: So you're not interested enough in good solutions (like my fast short oneliner) to answer questions... Ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use answer from [shubham koli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75205092/9475509) than create a new list as follow

```py
list = [
  [255, 255, 255],
  [255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0],
  [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0]
]


temp_list = []
for i in list:
    if i not in temp_list:
        temp_list.append(i)

result_list = []
for i in range(0, len(temp_list)):
  if i == 0:
    result_list.append(temp_list[i])
  else:
    n = list.count(temp_list[i])
    for j in range(n // 2):
      result_list.append(temp_list[i])

print(result_list)
```

which produces

```
[[255, 255, 255], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0]]
```

as requested. Number of repreated items is store in `n` and is obtained using `.count()` from a list. Later `n // 2` will give half of its value in integer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Counter class form collections to compute the number of repetition then a comprehension to repeat the distinct values half the number of times they occurred:

```
from collections import Counter

L = [[255, 255, 255], [255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], 
    [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0]]

R = [ t for t,count in Counter(map(tuple,L)).items() 
        for _ in range(count//2 or 1) ]

print(R)    
[(255, 255, 255), (255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0)]
```

Note that i'm converting the sublists into tuple because the Counter dictionary needs a hashable key value.  You can convert them back into lists in the comprehension if you need the output to be a list of lists.

**For consecutive repetitions:**

If your repetitions are always consecutive, you can use a more efficient approach by filtering/including every other repetition (at even relative occurence):

Using a simple loop:

```
include  = True
result   = L[:1]
for s in L[1:]:
    include = True if s != result[-1] else not include
    if include:
        result.append(s)

print(result)
[[255, 255, 255], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0]]
```

or the groupby/islice functions from itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby,islice

result = [ s for _,g in groupby(L) for s in islice(g,0,None,2) ]

print(result)
[[255, 255, 255], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0]]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
  res_lst = [item for k, item in enumerate(list) if k == 0 or k % 2 != 0]

    print(res_lst)

    res_lst = [[255, 255, 255], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0]]
```

Comment: I don't want to eliminate the duplicate elements in the list but divide by 2 the quantity that every single element is repeated. for example the element: [0, 255, 0] is repeated 6 times in the list; I expect in my new list to be repeated only 3 times.

Comment: check this method

Comment: I hope this is correct result

Comment: With this assumption, you can just do some slicing. Sadly they refuse to say whether this assumption is correct (I asked about it).

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.